# Error while using group_by and not while using arrange when subtracting two date columns R

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, aggregate, grouping

In the below dataframe, I am trying to identify the highest date from Col3 corresponding to each group based on Col1 and subtract Col2 dates from that highest date for each group to get the time difference in year in Col4:

```
Data_Frame <- data.frame(Col1 = c("A1", "A1", "A1", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A3", "A3", "A3"), 
                         
                         Col2 = c("2011-03-11", "2014-08-21", "2016-01-17", "2017-06-30", "2018-07-11", "2018-11-28", "2019-09-04", "2020-02-29", "2020-07-12"),
                         
                         Col3 = c("2018-10-22", "2019-05-24", "2020-12-25", "2018-10-12", "2019-09-24", "2020-12-19", "2018-10-22", "2019-06-14", "2020-12-20"))
```

The expected result is:

[image]

Neither of these options yield the result:

Option 1

```
Data_Frame <- Data_Frame %>% group_by(Col1) %>% mutate(Col4 = as.numeric(as.POSIXct(max(Data_Frame$Col3)) -  as.POSIXct(Data_Frame$Col2)) / 365.75)
```

Option 2

```
Data_Frame <- Data_Frame %>% group_by(Col1) %>% mutate(Col4 = as.numeric(difftime(max(Data_Frame$Col3), Data_Frame$Col2, unit="weeks"))/ 52.25)
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
> Data_Frame <- Data_Frame %>% group_by(Col1) %>% mutate(Col4 = as.numeric(as.POSIXct(max(Data_Frame$Col3)) -  as.POSIXct(Data_Frame$Col2)) / 365.75)
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `Col4`.
x Input `Col4` can't be recycled to size 3.
i Input `Col4` is `as.numeric(as.POSIXct(max(Data_Frame$Col3)) - as.POSIXct(Data_Frame$Col2))/365.75`.
i Input `Col4` must be size 3 or 1, not 9.
i The error occured in group 1: Col1 = "A1".
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
> rlang::last_error()
<error/dplyr_error>
Problem with `mutate()` input `Col4`.
x Input `Col4` can't be recycled to size 3.
i Input `Col4` is `as.numeric(as.POSIXct(max(Data_Frame$Col3)) - as.POSIXct(Data_Frame$Col2))/365.75`.
i Input `Col4` must be size 3 or 1, not 9.
i The error occured in group 1: Col1 = "A1".
Backtrace:
  1. dplyr::group_by(., Col1)
  9. dplyr::mutate(...)
 11. dplyr:::mutate_cols(.data, ...)
 12. base::tryCatch(...)
 13. base:::tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
 14. base:::tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
 15. value[[3L]](cond)
 16. dplyr:::stop_mutate_recycle_incompatible_size(e, index = i, dots = dots)
 17. dplyr:::stop_dplyr(...)
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see the full context.
```

Using arrange instead of group_by as shown below, however, works:

```
Data_Frame <- Data_Frame %>% arrange(Col1) %>% mutate(Col4 = as.numeric(as.POSIXct(max(Data_Frame$Col3)) -  as.POSIXct(Data_Frame$Col2)) / 365.75)

Data_Frame <- Data_Frame %>% arrange(Col1) %>% mutate(Col4 = as.numeric(difftime(max(Data_Frame$Col3), Data_Frame$Col2, unit="weeks"))/ 52.25)
```

What am I doing wrong through group_by statement and why does it not work?

The structure of the dataframe is:
[image]

Comment: Is there a reason you're doing `Data_Frame$Col2` instead of just `Col2`?

Comment: I thought I am selecting the column specifically by doing which.

Comment: Within a dplyr function you can just use the bare column name.

Comment: Removing which worked. Thanks.

Comment: Cool, I've put it down as an answer so if it solved your problem you can mark as resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within dplyr functions you can just write `Col2` (the bare column name) instead of `Data_Frame$Col2`.